# How to create view based animation in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have to add the following animation in my iOS app, I have used a scroll bar along with `UITableView` and achieved the top and bottom animation, but I'm still stuck at the middle animation part where the 4 `UIViews` come in a single horizontal line. Any suggestions?

http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/af8u4ulika9siddnf6k6hhrtg2_untitled-2.gif

Code:-

```
@implementation AnimatedView {
    UIScrollView *mainScroll;
    UIScrollView *backgroundScrollView;

    UILabel *_textLabel;
    UITableView *_commentsTableView;

    UIView *menuView;
    UIView *_commentsViewContainer;
    UIView *fadeView;

    UIImageView *imageView;

    NSMutableArray *comments;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        _mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame];
        self.view = _mainScrollView;

        _backgroundScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:HEADER_INIT_FRAME];
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:HEADER_INIT_FRAME];
        fadeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.frame];
        _textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 100.0f, 150.0f, 25.0f)];
        menuView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,_textLabel.frame.size.height+150, self.view.frame.size.width+30, 180)];

        [_backgroundScrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [_backgroundScrollView addSubview:fadeView];
        [_backgroundScrollView addSubview:menuView];
        [_backgroundScrollView addSubview:_textLabel];

        _commentsViewContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];
        _commentsTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
        _commentsTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        _commentsTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        [self.view addSubview:_backgroundScrollView];
        [_commentsViewContainer addSubview:_commentsTableView];
        [self.view addSubview:_commentsViewContainer];

        // fake data!
        comments = [@[@"Array for tableview"] mutableCopy];

    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark Scroll

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat delta = 0.0f;
    CGRect rect = HEADER_INIT_FRAME;

     // Here is where I do the "Zooming" image and the quick fade out the text and toolbar

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0.0f) {

        delta = fabs(MIN(0.0f, _mainScrollView.contentOffset.y));
        _backgroundScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect) - delta / 2.0f, CGRectGetMinY(rect) - delta, CGRectGetWidth(rect) + delta, CGRectGetHeight(rect) + delta);
        [_commentsTableView setContentOffset:(CGPoint){0,0} animated:NO];

    } else {
        delta = _mainScrollView.contentOffset.y;
        _textLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
        CGFloat backgroundScrollViewLimit = _backgroundScrollView.frame.size.height - kBarHeight;

        // Here I check whether or not the user has scrolled passed the limit where I want to stick the header, if they have then I move the frame with the scroll view
        // to give it the sticky header look

        if (delta > backgroundScrollViewLimit) {

            _backgroundScrollView.frame = (CGRect) {.origin = {0, delta - _backgroundScrollView.frame.size.height + kBarHeight}, .size = {self.view.frame.size.width, HEADER_HEIGHT}};
            _commentsViewContainer.frame = (CGRect){.origin = {0, CGRectGetMinY(_backgroundScrollView.frame) + CGRectGetHeight(_backgroundScrollView.frame)}, .size =                           _commentsViewContainer.frame.size };
            _commentsTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake (0, delta - backgroundScrollViewLimit);
            CGFloat contentOffsetY = -backgroundScrollViewLimit * kBackgroundParallexFactor;
            [_backgroundScrollView setContentOffset:(CGPoint){0,contentOffsetY} animated:NO];
        }
        else {
            _backgroundScrollView.frame = rect;
            _commentsViewContainer.frame = (CGRect){.origin = {0, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + CGRectGetHeight(rect)}, .size = _commentsViewContainer.frame.size };
            [_commentsTableView setContentOffset:(CGPoint){0,0} animated:NO];
            [_backgroundScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -delta * kBackgroundParallexFactor)animated:NO];
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    _mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), _commentsTableView.contentSize.height + CGRectGetHeight(_backgroundScrollView.frame));
}
```

Comment: Better than what?

Comment: @rckoenes  added current achieved part.

Comment: Post your code and specify where you think it can be better.

Comment: It looks like you don't actually want an animation here. What you want is to respond to the user scrolling the table and change the header accordingly. They are two very different things. Also, what happens if the user scrolls to the top again? Should it go back to how it started?

Comment: @GeneCode please refer above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any scrollview to implement this really. All you need is 1 `UITableView` with 2 sections. First section has a single empty element (but set the row height to 0), and enable the header for both sections. You can use UIViews for the `headerViews`. Then, you only need to change the header height (with icon positioning) based on tableview Delegate `scrollViewDidScroll`. `scrollViewDidScroll` is also a delegate of UITableView since one of TableView's element inherits from UIScrollView.